# How do I modify this Mapreduce code to also change the Entity's namespace?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, mapreduce

I'm using this mapper created by Ikai Lan:

```
package com.ikai.mapperdemo.mappers;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;

import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key;
import com.google.appengine.tools.mapreduce.AppEngineMapper;
import com.google.appengine.tools.mapreduce.DatastoreMutationPool;

/**
 *
 * The functionality of this is exactly the same as in {@link NaiveToLowercaseMapper}.
 * The advantage here is that since a {@link DatastoreMutationPool} is used, mutations
 * can be done in batch, saving API calls.
 *
 * @author Ikai Lan
 *
 */
public class PooledToLowercaseMapper extends
        AppEngineMapper<Key, Entity, NullWritable, NullWritable> {
    private static final Logger log = Logger
            .getLogger(PooledToLowercaseMapper.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void map(Key key, Entity value, Context context) {
        log.info("Mapping key: " + key);

        if (value.hasProperty("comment")) {
            String comment = (String) value.getProperty("comment");
            comment = comment.toLowerCase();
            value.setProperty("comment", comment);
            value.setProperty("updatedAt", new Date());

            DatastoreMutationPool mutationPool = this.getAppEngineContext(
                    context).getMutationPool();
            mutationPool.put(value);
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to do in addition to the above is also change the datastore namespace of the entity that is being modified.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The namespace is a component of an Entity's immutable key. There is no notion of changing it. If you're trying to 'move' an entity into a different namespace, you'll need to create a new entity in that namespace, track down any references to the old entity and update them, then delete the old entity.

Comment: Ok. Good to know. But my real problem is I don't know how to create an Entity in a particular namespace **in the context of this MapReduce code**. For example, I could do something like this: `Entity newOne = new Entity("Kind", id);` to create a new Entity - `but I don't know how to set its namespace`. There is a `getNamespace` method but no `setNamespace`? Will the `NamespaceManager` work here to set the namespace?

Comment: `NamespaceManager` is what you need. It has both a `.get()` and a `.set()`. When an Entity is created, the current namespace is used implicitly. See http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/NamespaceManager.html